# ElasticSearch check the list of ids existance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of ids like this:

```
['019ca83d-4f77-58df-8da7-9aee205108c3', '07c59f45-71f2-58e0-9ce9-08d687cc9dc8', '154b3a69-d3d2-5f04-b0cb-3f0536f822d9']
```

and I need to check which of them already present in the elastic search.
I tried this request:

```
{
  "_source": ["_id"]
  "query": {
     "ids": {
       "type": "_doc", 
       "values": ['019ca83d-4f77-58df-8da7-9aee205108c3', 
                  '07c59f45-71f2-58e0-9ce9-08d687cc9dc8', 
                  '154b3a69-d3d2-5f04-b0cb-3f0536f822d9']
     }
  }
}
```

But it will also return the documents which not present in that list.
My ElasticSearch version is 6.7. 
Can someone please help me to generate a proper request?

Comment: Can you show an id that is returned but shouldn't ?